# Use XDebug on a multi-user environment

Tags: apache2, xdebug, vhosts

I'm developing on a shared local server with some other people. This server has one Apache/PHP instance, but then it has multiple "sites-available" (VirtualHost) for different people.

I would like to get XDebug working so every one of us can use it independently. The problem is that if we enable XDebug and, for example, my IDE is connected to the server and I set a breakpoint, it'll stop if other person is browsing the page, even if it's in his/her own VirtualHost.

Any hints on how to properly set this up?

**Edit:**

Forgot to mention that the webserver is running in Docker.
This is the current configuration of XDebug:

```
# automatically start debugger on every request
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000

# send all debug requests to 127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
xdebug.remote_host=host.docker.internal

#log all xdebug requests to see is it working correctly
xdebug.remote_log=/var/log/debug.log
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This should not happen at all, unless you have `xdebug.remote_autostart` turned on, **and** have hard coded `xdebug.remote_host` (instead of using `xdebug.remote_connect_back`). You don't want to hard code `xdebug.remote_host` in a multi-user environment really.

Debugging sessions are only initialised when the XDEBUG_SESSION_START is detected (which is what the browser extension will set, or when that is added to the GET/POST parameters)--and continued requests.

There is also no such concept as:

> my IDE is connected to the server

Upon every request, Xdebug (if set to trigger with the cookie) will connect **to** the IDE. And it uses the `xdebug.remote_host` setting, or the inferred IP address if `xdebug.remote_connect_back` is enabled to connect **to**. And the end of the request, that connection is severed. You can use `xdebug.remote_log=/tmp/xdebug.log` to create a log file, which will indicate when connections are being made, and whether they work.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Derick. about this: "my IDE is connected to the server", my mistake. I meant the other way around, as you said, XDebug will connect to the IDE.
I will try what you said and see if it works

Comment: I have been taking a look, Derick. As you said remote_autostart and remote_host are set. I've edited my original question with the current configuration. The web server is running on Docker. and I wasn't the one configuring the stuff. So I'm not really sure if something would be different for XDebug given that it's running on Docker

Comment: I've been trying some setups also... and now seems like XDebug is getting something. but: [5329] I: Remote address found, connecting to 10.255.0.2:9000.
[5329] E: Time-out connecting to client (Waited: 200 ms). :-(
I guess that has to do with XDebug being in a Docker container? so it's not picking the right IP Address? My computer address inside my local network is something like 192.168...

Comment: That's a sign that you still have remote_connect_back on? That isn't going to work with docker, due to different sub-networks that Docker does. I'm not sure how to do multi-user with a case where docker gets in the way. I'm not quite sure how to square this circular hole.